# XPDL / BPMN 2.0 - What are the objectives?

Tags: workflow, bpmn

I'm a little bit confused about `BPMN 2.0` and `XPDL` formats. They're complementary or they have very different objectives?

`BPMN` < 2.0 was only to graphic notation, and `XPDL` was to get graphic notation / interaction of the elements.

But today `BPMN 2.0` fits all the requirements of `XPDL`? What's the needing of a `BPMN` engine to support `XPDL`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, BPMN 2.0 and XPDL are not complementary.

BPMN 2.0 provides both a definition of the graphical language and the underlying XML standard.
If a BPX engine supports BPMN 2.0, it does not necessarily need to support XDPL, but might do so, e.g. in case an interface to an XPDL compatible and not BPMN 2.0 compatible tool exists.

I know for sure that there are vendors and projects in this area who are strongly focusing on BPMN 2.0 and are largely ignoring XPDL, e.g. for BPMN 2.0 seems to be more successful in facilitating consent regarding the interchange of diagrams: http://www.omgwiki.org/bpmn-miwg/doku.php

Comment: So, the focus of BPMN 2.0 and XPDL are equals, right? I`m thinking about this because we already support BPMN 2.0 formats, but for one client, we need to convert XPDL processes into BPMN processes. I`ve not seen any converter yet, just one hosted app on Business Process Incubator.

Comment: Technical, it would be probably be correct to say that while BPMN was initially just the graphical notation and XPDL a corresponding XML standard, BPMN 2.0 is now both.
When it comes to converting XPDL to BPMN it seems to be a very complex issue, as the way XPDL is actually implemented might differ from vendor to vendor. In my experience, BPMN 2.0 is in this question "more mature".

Answer (score 0):

Trisotech Company through businessprocessincubator.com services, and it's web modeler has the feature of converting XPDL(2.1, 2.2, 3) to BPMN and reverse.

http://www.businessprocessincubator.com/convert-xpdl-to-bpmn-with-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Late answer.

As stated in previous answer, BPMN was initially only a notation from OMG, and XPDL a format for interchange of workflow model from Wfmc.

XPDL 2.0 relies on BPMN as a notation, i.e. Wfmc prevented creating its own notation in order to avoid standard war and overlapping between competing standards.

With version 2, BPMN came also with an exchange format, being with XML Model Interchange or an XML Schema in XSD.

However, it is important to point out that BPMN covers as well workflow model (i.e. orchestration with sequenced activities) than not executable models such as choreography or conversation. Also, BPMN doesn't come with an architecture of reference for a workflow system. So the scope is larger and the focus is less precise than for XPDL and Wfmc.

For these reasons, I think that tools relying on XPDL and Wfmc architecture are more mature in terms of interoperability. I particularly appreciate implementation such as Shark and JaWe when willing to understand well architecture of reference of Wfmc and XPDL with BPMN representation. Other implementations exist relying on XPDL 2.0, e.g. Bizagi.

However, one weakness of XPDL 2 is that the way the modeling constructs of a workflow model are represented with BPMN visual elements is not explicitly stated (e.g. a line is a representation of an actor).Such mapping is quite well done in workflow systems originally based on XPDL (e.g. Shark).

In the reverse, I never identified any initiative in the BPMN community related to workflow engines and modelers interoperability. The working group for BPMN interoperability was more addressing exchanges between modelers.

So interoperability based on BPMN 2.0 between workflow engines is also a subject to improvement.